# C++ reinterpret_cast safety with array references and move/copy assignment

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, reference, reinterpret-cast

My teammates are writing a fixed-size implementation of `std::vector` for a safety-critical application. We're not allowed to use heap allocation, so they created a simple array wrapper like this:

```
template <typename T, size_t NUM_ITEMS>
class Vector
{
public:
    void push_back(const T& val);

    ...more vector methods

private:
    // Internal storage
    T storage_[NUM_ITEMS];

    ...implementation
};
```

A problem we encountered with this implementation is that it requires elements present default constructors (which is not a requirement of `std::vector` and created porting difficulties). I decided to hack on their implementation to make it behave more like `std::vector` and came up with this:

```
template <typename T, size_t NUM_ITEMS>
class Vector
{
public:
    void push_back(const T& val);

    ...more vector methods
private:
    // Internal storage
    typedef T StorageType[NUM_ITEMS];
    alignas(T) char storage_[NUM_ITEMS * sizeof(T)];

    // Get correctly typed array reference
    StorageType& get_storage() { return reinterpret_cast<T(&)[NUM_ITEMS]>(storage_); }
    const StorageType& get_storage() const { return reinterpret_cast<const T(&)[NUM_ITEMS]>(storage_); }
};
```

I was then able to just search and replace `storage_` with `get_storage()` and everything worked. An example implementation of `push_back` might then look like:

```
template <typename T, size_t NUM_ITEMS>
void Vector<T, NUM_ITEMS>::push_back(const T& val)
{
    get_storage()[size_++] = val;
}
```

In fact, it worked so easily that it got me thinking.. Is this a good/safe use of `reinterpret_cast`? Is the code directly above a suitable alternative to placement new, or are there risks associated with copy/move assignment to an uninitialized object?

EDIT: In response to a comment by NathanOliver, I should add that we cannot use the STL, because we cannot compile it for our target environment, nor can we certify it.

Comment: `get_storage()[size_++] = val;` is not legal.  There is not actual object in that location so you can't assign to it.  You need to use placement new to construct the objects at the correct location.  To make your life easy why not just use a `std::vector` and give it a stack allocator that has a fixed size buffer it gives the vector to use?

Comment: @NathanOliver We cannot use the STL because we cannot certify or compile it for our target environment. I agree that placement new is a better approach here, but it should be noted that the existing code builds and passes rigorous unit testing with three separate compilers.

Comment: @AdamBurroughs Then you're missing some important unit tests, since the container never creates or destroys the objects it claims to own. The simplest one would be, use a `T` where the destructor has side effects, and expect those side effects when the life of a non-empty `Vector<T,N>` ends.

Comment: What is the types of T's you are using?  Without using placement new you don't actually create any objects do if they aren't trivial your in UB land

Comment: @aschepler -- That's a good point, but AFAIK, placement new wouldn't solve this problem. Manual destruction would be required either way.

Comment: @AdamBurroughs Well, sure, placement new must essentially always be paired with manual destructor calls, similarly to how `malloc` is paired with `free` and raw new-expressions are paired with raw delete-expressions.

Answer (score 2):

The code you've shown is only safe for POD types (Plain Old Data), where the object's representation is trivial and thus assignment to an unconstructed object is ok.

If you want this to work in all generality (which i assume you do due to using a template), then for a type `T` it is undefined behavior to use the object prior to construction it. That is, you must construct the object before your e.g. assignment to that location. That means you need to call the constructor explicitly on demand. The following code block demonstrates an example of this:

```
template <typename T, size_t NUM_ITEMS>
void Vector<T, NUM_ITEMS>::push_back(const T& val)
{
    // potentially an overflow test here

    // explicitly call copy constructor to create the new object in the buffer
    new (reinterpret_cast<T*>(storage_) + size_) T(val);

    // in case that throws, only inc the size after that succeeds
    ++size_;
}
```

The above example demonstrates placement new, which takes the form `new (void*) T(args...)`. It calls the constructor but does not actually perform an allocation. The visual difference is the inclusion of the `void*` argument to operator new itself, which is the address of the object to act on and call the constructor for.

And of course when you remove an element you'll need to destroy that explicitly as well. To do this for a type `T`, simply call the pseudo-method `~T()` on the object. Under templated context the compiler will work out what this means, either an actual destructor call, or no-op for e.g. int or double. This is demonstrated below:

```
template<typename T, size_t NUM_ITEMS>
void Vector<T, NUM_ITEMS>::pop_back()
{
    if (size_ > 0) // safety test, you might rather this throw, idk
    {
        // explicitly destroy the last item and dec count
        // canonically, destructors should never throw (very bad)
        reinterpret_cast<T*>(storage_)[--size_].~T();
    }
}
```

Also, I would avoid returning a refernce to an array in your `get_storage()` method, as it has length information and would seem to imply that all elements are valid (constructed) objects, which of course they're not. I suggest you provide methods for getting a pointer to the start of the contiguous array of constructed objects, and another method for getting the number of constructed objects. These are the `.data()` and `.size()` methods of e.g. `std::vector<T>`, which would make use of your class less jarring to seasoned C++ users.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this a good/safe use of reinterpret_cast?
>
> Is the code directly above a suitable alternative to placement new

No. No.

> or are there risks associated with copy/move assignment to an uninitialized object?

Yes. The behaviour is undefined.

1. Assuming memory is uninitialised, copying the vector has undefined behaviour.
2. No object of type `T` has started its lifetime at the memory location. This is super bad when `T` is not trivial.
3. The reinterpretation violates the strict aliasing rules.

First is fixed by value-initialising the storage. Or by making the vector non-copyable and non-movable.

Second is fixed by using placement new.

Third is technically fixed by using using the pointer returned by placement new, but you can avoid storing that pointer by `std::launder`ing after reinterpreting the storage.